# How to get data from other site

Tags: php, dom, text

I'm making a website and it'll have a user page on which will be user score. I'm taking that score from the other website but the problem is how to do that: how to get text from any element on any website?
I wanted to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728453/how-do-i-get-text-from-a-website-using-php) but I don't know how to select that **th** from which I need text because the whole table hasn't any IDs, only a class. You can see in the code, I want text from the place where is written: **I NEED THIS**.

Thanks.

```
<table class="profile" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
            <h3>TEXT</h3>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right">
            TEXT</br>
            TEXT</br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <table class="score_stats">
            <tr><th>TEXT</th><th>   **I NEED THIS**   </th></tr>
            <tr><td>TEXT</td><td>NUMBER</td></tr>
            <tr><td>TEXT</td><td>NUMBER</td></tr>
            <tr><td>TEXT</td><td>NUMBER</td></tr>
            <tr><td>TEXT</td><td>NUMBER</td></tr>
            <tr><td>TEXT</td><td>NUMBER</td></tr>
       </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the html code of the page , in string or array
   Many choices here >>[How do I get the HTML code of a web page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819182/how-do-i-get-the-html-code-of-a-web-page-in-php)

2.Split those strings or things you need with some simple code , I know you could find it by yourself

Hope this helps

Poom

Comment: Well I can't say that I understand this because I'm a starter in PHP. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I need the url that you're using, Can I have it because there are many method and I can choose the best for you

Comment: I made something(you can see it in my answer), it's working. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After the whole day of trying I made this:

```
function getPlayerScore($url){
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
    $finder = new DOMXpath( $dom );
    $nodes = $finder->query( "//*[@class='score_stats']/tr" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $nodes = str_split($nodes, 11);
    return $nodes[1];
}

getPlayerScore($user['playercp'])
```

...and it's working.